# How can I read a line and split it to save it? And do the same for a second file

Tags: java, arrays, list, bufferedreader

I have been trying to read my txt file into java and then splitting the two integer columns to then be saved into a list or array. I need these two numbers seperated because I will be uploading a second txt file in which I will have more numbers that I will need to add or substract from the first files columns.

So here is a sample of my txt files: 
file 1:

0033 2000

2390 500

etc.

file 2:

0033 2 400

3829 1 3020

etc.

The first file has two columns and the second file has three columns

To be very honest I'm not good with java at all. So far I have only been able to read the files and print them as they are.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class test {

    public static void readlines(File f) throws IOException {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(f);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        int NumberOfLines = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

          System.out.println(line); 
          NumberOfLines++;

        }

        System.out.println("Number of lines read: " + NumberOfLines);
        br.close();
        fr.close();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("filename1");
        File s = new File("filename2");
        try {
            readlines(f);
            readlines(s);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

I know that I should be splitting the data using .split("\t") since it's a tab but how can I save this into a column array so that I can later on in a different class add then together? Do I need to make two classes in which I read file1 and in the second file 2? Afterwards I do all my adding in the main class?

Any ideas will be nice here!! Sorry for asking basic stuff but switching from matlab to java is kind of difficult for me D:

Comment: If you're asking how to get your split values into an array, String.split() already does that. String[] array = String.split("\t") will give you an array of of values, split by the \t delimiter.

Comment: @sleepToken I understand what I did wrong with split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'd do is to make the `readlines(File f)` method return an array. Arrays (in case you don't know) are lists or (commonly) similar elements. For example, in your case, that method would return a String array. `split()` method returns an array of String, where each element is one of the splitted elements. For example:

`String[] splitted = "Hello World!".split(' ');`

In this case, `splitted` would be: `["Hello", "World!"]`

If you make `readlines(File f)` return an array with the splitted read content, all you have to do in your main (if you want to keep this "matrix" appereance) is to push the returned value into another Array.

I hope I explained it clear enough ^^

Comment: Thank you very much, I think I get it now!!

Comment: If you have any other issue around this, feel free to come back! ^^